# How would you calculate the Mandelbrot set in hardware?

Tags: math, floating-point

I'd like to build a small novelty circuit that calculates the [Mandelbrot set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mandelbrot_set) and displays it on an array of LEDs. The minimum floating point math would not necessarily require complex numbers (just calculate \$x\$ and \$y\$ separately) and the total number of individual calculations of \$z_{n+1}=z_n^2+c\$ would be under one million, so even something as slow as *ten million FLOPS per hour* would be OK in this case. At this level, it looks like 16 bit math is almost enough with clever programming, 32-bits is enough to make it work. Floats rather than ints would make life a heck of a lot easier, but not required.

I believe that a Raspberry Pi would be overkill as would a high-end Arduino, so an [Uno](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Arduino_boards_and_compatible_systems#Official), or a [Basic Stamp II](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BASIC_Stamp#Versions) with its [FP coprocessor](https://www.parallax.com/downloads/um-pfu-datasheet) perhaps.

That exhausts my knowledge of the possibilities, but there must be other options out there. How would you go about designing a small circuit to do this? What type of circuit would you use?

*[Background question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2358889/284619), and the [first ever published image](http://abel.math.harvard.edu/archive/118r_spring_05/docs/brooksmatelski.pdf) of the Mandelbrot set (1978):*

[image]

Comment: Are you planning to run Python or will you recode in C? If Python, stick with a RPI.

Comment: @DoxyLover no not at all. *I will learn whatever I have to* in order to code on the recommended platform. Python here was just to show how my calculated image was generated, and to give some overall impression of what a calculation might be like. I don't know how to write proper *pseudocode*.

Comment: Close-voter; I'm looking for a set of a few small chips that can do this calculation in order to produce an array of binary values to drive an array of LEDs. The \$m \times n\$ LED driver should be fairly standard so I haven't asked about that part. I've added extra material because I can't always stay on line to respond to requests for additional information, and yes some of that is math, but I'm after a recommendation for a set of chips to implement this circuit.

Comment: You haven't said how fast you want it. Basically anything will do it if you wait long enough - here's a Xerox Alto doing it with TTL logic: http://www.righto.com/2017/06/one-hour-mandelbrot-creating-fractal-on.html

Comment: @pjc50 sure I did! "...so even something as slow as *ten million FLOPS per hour* would be OK in this case." OK I'll take a look, but that's a whole computer and I'm looking for just a few chips, enough to calculate for this roughly 35x75 matrix of LEDs. I'm looking for something minimal and small (complexity, not physical size), so *old* definitely works, thanks!

Comment: .. so options I'd consider for this are PIC32 (no floating point, but DSP for doing fixed point in parallel), or ARM Cortex M4 with FPU e.g. STM32F4. I would also suggest looking at the source to FRACTINT: http://www.nahee.com/spanky/www/fractint/getting.html

Comment: .. or Atmel even have it as an example program http://asf.atmel.com/docs/latest/uc3c/html/avr32_2applications_2uc3c-fpu-fractal-demo_2main_8c.html

Comment: @pjc50 that's better than wire-wrapping a bunch of TTL shifters and registers. I'll check those out, thanks. btw I'm strictly asking for the chips here. I'll learn whatever programming required, don't need programing recommendations.

Comment: Just pointing out that every AVR chip (as far as I know, it's all, thanks to a library) can do division and FP(floating point) arithmetic (FPU), yet there's no assembler command for division, and there's no FPU to deal with the FP arithmetic. It's all done in software, there's no hardware solution for FP arithmetic on Arduinos. And I'm **very** certain that you can include a similar library for picXX or any other microcontroller. Check out this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34239178/how-does-an-avr-perform-floating-point-arithmetic)

Comment: @HarrySvensson I see what you mean - does this even include the [six-pin tinyAVR](http://www.atmel.com/products/microcontrollers/avr/tinyAVR.aspx)? Somehow that image really appeals to me (never mind the required support for getting information in and out)!  This task can probably be done with fixed precision as well, based on test.

Comment: Hmmm, I'm not 100% sure if it will work with every tinyAVR, some only got 512B flash, it might be difficult to fit everything onto that.  And sorry for asking this question, but why can't you just store the mandelbrot image in a lookup table? Or are you going to make some super duper mega slow animation zooming in forever?

Comment: @HarrySvensson got it. The shape of Mandelbrot set was never really seen until it could be computed, and then until someone actually did it. The novelty-circuit I'm talking about would be perhaps an illustration of how things have changed in 40 years. Thus I'm sticking to the same grid spacing as was used in the first ever visualization and a roughly 35x75 matrix of LEDs.

Comment: You don't need to change the grid spacing if you use a lookup table. You would only need 35x75 bits => 35x80 bits => 35x10 bytes => a list of 350 bytes. But it doesn't matter ;) I assume that you've gotten all the answers you need ;) Also, I'm very very sure that a tinyAVR that got 2kB flash could fit the FPU library on it without any problems + your own code. As long as you use atmelstudio as your coding environment... The Arduino IDE injects so much weird crap onto the controllers...

Comment: I believe the only question here is "Why?". Why struggling to do it with a "small micro"? You have a huge array of LEDs, so power taken by micro is no issue and so is space taken.  So relax and do it with some powerfull micro you are comfortable in programming. Also consider you will for sure going to add features as soon as you get the basic thing working. Go for overkilling!

Comment: @carloc I disagree that that is the *only* question, but it is a question. You might look again at [this comment](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/317514/#comment739838_317514) above, or again at the part in the question where it says "(a little more [background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JJh83.jpg))" and the comments there.

Comment: 1. Comments are for clarifications, _NOT_ answering the question. 2. This question is obviously asking for a component, which is off-topic. Trying to get around it by wording it as a "set" of components doesn't avoid that.

Comment: @pipe Comments are comments as its name tells. If you browse this site you'll find only a small part of them "asking for clatifications"

Comment: Well I have gone through it again. I haven't found anything calling for a small micro to do your plots. But I shall admit I overlooked one very good reason to your point: It's a challenge I want do it with as little as can be done. In this I do agree with you.

Comment: @pipe can you help me out here and point to the specific rule of which you speak? I don't understand your distinction between "component" and "components" and so far I don't see anything that addresses either in the help center, but if it is there, I'd appreciate help finding it. Thanks!

Comment: electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @W5VO thanks but I've looked there a few times and I don't see in what way the user feels there's a problem with this question based on "asking for a component". You've probably seen the [meta question](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6273/102305), if you can elaborate there it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: @pipe Thank you for the edit! This looks much cleaner, more concise and more structured than what I'd originally posted.

Answer (score 1):

I think the moset obvious solution for your requirements is using a **FPGA** and writing HDL code that calculates  \$z_{i+1} = z_i^2  + c\$.

Comment: A search for "smallest FPGA" certainly comes up with several very small ones. I wouldn't have even considered it, but ya, this is downright elegant!

Answer (score 1):

Any Cortex M4F can easily do single-precision floating point math (ie. float, not double). [Here is a summary how long each instruction takes.](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0439b/BEHJADED.html)

Example: Kinetis MK02FN128 running at 100MHz can theoretically do 100 million floating point multiplications **a second**.

You would write code in C with floats as you would do on a PC. [Some tips.](https://community.arm.com/processors/b/blog/posts/10-useful-tips-to-using-the-floating-point-unit-on-the-arm-cortex--m4-processor)
Just look for microcontrollers with Cortex M4**F** core or "with FPU".

Comment: Thanks for the links!! What's the smallest option here? The speed is amazing, but I'm looking for "small".

Comment: There is a myriad of ARM MCUs to choose from.... some better-known families to look at: Kinetis, STM32, EFM32, Renesas Synergy, TM4C. You can even get a Bluetooth system on chip with FPU - nrf52 (in a module eg. BL652).

Comment: Do you mean "small" as in chip package size, or some other metric? The Kinetis is a whole 5mm x 5mm, and the really small packages can't be hand-assembled.